# Looking for a way to draw a line between two points on a sphere in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

My app (a flight tracker) needs to draw a line between two points (cities say) on a sphere (earth) along the surface (i.e. the great circle route) using Three.js.

I can think of 2 ways - (a) creating Three.js 'Line' with a set of (enough) points that I calculate manually and (b) writing the lines into the texture I use for the sphere after it's loaded but before I apply it as a texture.

I can see problems with both (not even sure if (b) is possible in Three.js yet) - anyone think of a better way or have an opinion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: b works. Load your image into a canvas element, paint line(s) and use the canvas as texture. Use texture.needsUpdate on updates. What's your problem with a ?

Comment: Thank you all - apologies for late reply - I hoped the site would alert me when answers came in.

Answer (score 1):

You use many particles to create a kind of dotted line.